# Pydev problems with "Go to definition" and "package Explorer"

Tags: python, eclipse, package, definition, pydev

I'm using Pydev on Eclipse. I have created a new project, added `__init__.py` and a module in a package in the src folder. The problem is, I can't see classes and functions outlines when I try to expand the module by clicking the arrow left to it. Nothing expands. I expect to see a list of classes with a capital "C" letter left to each class name, and "F" letter with functions. But nothing is displayed.
Another problem is, when I Ctrl+click on a function or method, it just plays a ring sound, and does not go to definiton. Under "Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter -python" menu, I added the "src" folder to "Libraries" but it again does not go to definition.
Could you please help me with these two problems?
Thanks,
Best regards,

Comment: Your second attempted fix should fix your problem. Try adding all subdirectories and the parent of src to "Libraries" as well

Comment: Well, it didn't fix it !(http://i56.tinypic.com/4rp02b.png)  !(http://i51.tinypic.com/20qnxmp.png) have a look at the images please

Comment: I'm not quite sure, then - sorry

Answer (score 1):

add your code dir into the `project->properties->PyDev - PYTHONPATH->sourceFolders`,  you can find the C mark in the package Explorer

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Pydev 1.6.5 and I also can't view the outline when I expand the module. For this I use the Outline view, see the screenshot:

[image]

Did you add the view?

```
Window > Show view > Other > General > Outline
```

About Q2, the "go to definition" feature is documented on [a Pydev page](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_gotodef.html) and in some situations it *can* work (not guaranted).

If you are using an old release (< 2.0), my suggestion is to upgrade, and if you still have problems consider to  [open an issue](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=85796&atid=577329). Pydev is very useful but actually far from perfection :-(

Comment: Hi, yes I have added the Outline view, but it is empty. I use the latest versions of eclipse (3.6.2) and pydev (2.002)

Comment: Does changing to Pydev perspective solve the issue? Window > Open perspective > Other > Pydev.